# Tool for making Flash games

Tags: flash

Good day!
I am planning to create a flash game on my own.
Is there an opensource tool for making flash games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave almost no info about the type of game you're planning to build, but if you're looking to make a platformer, [The Citrus Engine](http://citrusengine.com/) is really great. It's open source now, too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually im planning to creat just 2D sample flash games.

Comment: i already downloaded CitrusEngineV3-Beta1. How ever i dont know how to install the engine. Is there additional download that I needed?

Comment: There isn't anything to install - it's a set of AS3 libraries that make up the engine. There are some example FLA's in the "fla" folder.

Comment: Perhaps we need more info about what you're looking for - are you an experienced AS3 developer? Are you looking for an engine or an entire IDE to build a game inside of?

Comment: I am new to AS3. I used to program desktop applications using java. As of now I like to create a stand alone flash game. Im looking for an entire IDE.

Comment: The Citrus Engine includes a level editor GUI to make your levels in, but otherwise you will be doing mostly AS3 coding. Most-all Flash game "tools" are going to be frameworks for you to code on top of. The only full-on game IDE that exports to Flash that I know of is Unity, though that is a heavy 3D game engine (you could still do 2D in it if you wanted). @zshall mentioned ClickTeam's Multimedia Fusion, which I've never heard of, but it looks like an IDE. All-in-all, you're going to have to (and should) do extensive AS3 coding to make a Flash game.

Answer (score 5):

Unity 3D is not open source but it's free of charge:
http://unity3d.com/create-games/ (if you like their [license](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses))
(there is also a pro version for $ - but maybe the free one is enough for you

Comment: Unity3D makes *flash* games now?

Answer (score 2):

I'd also check out [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) if you are looking for free Flash development software.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a Flash game **framework** or a standalone program that will create the game for you?

http://code.google.com/p/flashgamemaker/ and http://pushbuttonengine.com/ are two open-source frameworks I found. In terms of a standalone program, ClickTeam's Multimedia Fusion can make flash games without any code, but it isn't free.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by *tool* but there are a tonne of *libraries* in ActionScript that will establish a foundation for various games. Here are a few:

- [Flixel](http://www.flixel.org/)
- [FlashPunk](http://flashpunk.net/)
- [Openspace-Engine](http://www.openspace-engine.com/index.php)

See more here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/gaming_engines.html